# Como puedo colocar un caracter en un if en C

Tags: c, neovim

Estoy intentando aprender C  y quiero hacer algo para intentar ver lo que aprendí y cuando quiero colocar un char en el if me da una advertencia(es editor de código que estoy usando es lunarvim)
Alguien me puede ayudar?
Quiero hacer que en el caso 5 pregunte si estoy bien y eso se guardaria en la variable caso5 y en el if ver en el caso que diga "si" o "no" o que sea que siga s o n eso me da igual y que en el caso que diga algo que no sea eso diga que lo vuelva a intentar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int caso;
  char caso5;
  printf("Hola Ingrese Su Caso Del 0 al 5\n");
  scanf("%i",&caso);

  switch (caso) {
    case 0:
      printf("Ok se le asignara su caso(el caso 0), pronto l@ llamaremos\n");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("De acuerdo espere la cola, estamos teniendo mucha gente con este caso\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Vaya Caso Mas Fuerte sera contactado enseguida *se sorprende UwU*\n");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("Al parecer no tenemos soporte para este caso lamentamos las molestias\n");
      printf("Si desea tener ayuda con este caso por favor contacte a support@c11.casos.cl para ayuda\n");
      break;
    case 4:
      printf("LLAME\nAL\n9\n1\n1\nYA!");
      break;
    case 5:
      printf("Seguro de que esta bien?\n(si o no)\n");
      scanf("%c",&caso5);
      
      if (caso5 =="si") { // aqui me da error y no se porque es 
        printf("Entonces reinicie el programa este es un caso grave, no para bromas\n");
      }
      break;

    default:
      printf("No se pudo completar la accion intentelo de nuevo\n");
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay que ser experto para entender los mensajes que el compilador te da. La mayoría de las veces podrás comprenderlos sabiendo conceptos básicos del lenguaje y un poco de inglés.

Cuando compilas el código obtienes el siguiente mensaje:

> code.tio.c:30:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Traducido quiere decir:

> code.tio.c:30:17: advertencia: comparación entre puntero y entero

El compilador te está advirtiendo sobre una comparación entre tipos diferentes y posiblemente no obtengas el resultado esperado.

Es una advertencia, no un error, ya que existen [conversiones implícitas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) que permiten que la operación ocurra.

---

`"si"` es un [literal de string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), un arreglo de caracteres (tipo `const char[N]`).

`caso5` es una variable de tipo `char` y solo puede contener un caracter.

Lo que en realidad quieres hacer es la siguiente comparación:

```
caso5 == 's'
```

Nota que la sutil diferencia entre los literales de string y caracteres es que los primeros están rodeados de comillas dobles mientras que los segundos de comillas simples.